# What is the difference between $N=(2,2)$ with $N=(2,2)^*$ in 2d?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

What is the difference between $N=(2,2)$ with $N=(2,2)^*$ in 2 dimensional theory?

In some sense, i heard, they are totally different theory. 
I heard from breaking of $N=(4,4)$ supersymmetry it comes $N=(2,2)^*$. 
What is the crucial difference between  $N=(2,2)$ with $N=(2,2)^*$?

Comment: Please consider adding relevant links and explanations to your question, it is currently quite unclear what the $N = (k,l)$ *are* that you are talking about.

Comment: As explained [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/24121/what-is-the-difference-between-%24n-2-2-%24-with-%24n-2-2-%24?show=24128#a24128), the * probably means that the (2,2) theory is obtained from a theory with a higher amount of supersymmetry.

Comment: @ACuriousMind , sorry for late response, this is the case of 2 dimensional case

Comment: and $N=(k,l)$ corresponds the A side and B side of theory. Since i am just beginner of seiberg-witten theory, i don't know what is A side and B side in detail....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2d $N=(2,2)^*$ is a reduction of $N=(4,4)$ with some mass condition. 
The difference between $N=(2,2)$ and $N=(4,4)$ in 2d, can be distinguished by considering 4d $N=1$, $N=2$ theories. (The number of supersymmetric charges are key factor for distinguished them)

i.e

4 dimensional $N=1$ supersymmetry has 4 supercharges, and from dimensional reduction, it corresponds to 2 dimensional $N=(2,2)$ theories. In similar way 4d $N=2$ supersymmetry relates with 2 d $N=(4,4) \rightarrow N=(2,2)^*$